# Find function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

Find the function $f$ such that

$f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $

and   such that  around zero   satisfies the equation

$f(z) = z + f(z^2) $

I found that this function

$f(z)=C+z+z^2+z^4+z^8+\cdots$

for any constant $C$, solve the problem.

But I found it only trying. I'd like to understand how to tackle the problem in a right way.
can someone help me? thanks

Comment: That series doesn't define a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What does it mean by "around $0$"? Is it the functional equation is true on a neighbourhood of $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With function definitions of this kind, it is often a matter of expanding the r.h.s. of the equation: $$f(z) = z + f(z^2) = z + z^2 + f(z^4) = z + z^2 + z^4 + f(z^8) = \ldots$$
As for the constant term, you get that from $z = 0$: $$f(0) = 0 + f(0)$$ which is true for any value $f(0) = C$.

Comment: Note the series expansion in the OP doesn't define a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, so this is not enough.

Comment: Sure, if the question is on how to extend the function to all of $\mathbb{C}$, there is more work to be done. But I took this particular question to be about getting an expression for $f$ around 0 without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's not much to add to what you did. Assuming that there is a solution of the form $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$, then$$a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots=f(z)=z+f(z^2)=a_0+z+a_1z^2+a_2z^4+\cdots$$and therefore

- $a_0$ can be anything;
- $a_1=1$;
- $a_2=a_1=1$;
- $a_3=0$;
- $a_4=a_2=1$;
- $a_5=0$;
- $a_6=0$

and so on. Therefore, if $n\in\mathbb N$ is *not* a power of $2$, then $a_n=0$. Other than that, we have $a_{2^n}=1$.

Comment: So you are assuming that the given function is analytic.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad If you want to make it look difficult, then the answer is affirmative. But I like to think that I made the algebraic manipulations that were appropriate to find an answer.

Comment: That series does not define a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, I noticed. But it seems likely that what the OP meant was a complex function defined near $0$ on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Jose: Hrm. I assumed the opposite; that the OP meant what he wrote, and that this exercise turns out to be about analytic continuations.

Comment: @Hurkyl That would make this an exercise on Complex Analysis. I doubt that. I edited the tags of the question; originally, there was a single one, which was `abstract-algebra`.